# .htaccess RewriteRule skip URI that has query params

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

I'm attempting to re-route all traffic on a local wordpress instance (ran by MAMP) from

`localhost:8080/mydomain` to `localhost:8080/mydomain/dashboard` with an exception. I don't want to re-route the URI if it has query parameters like this:

`localhost:8080/mydomain/?post_type=ignition_product&p=23&preview=1` . The query paramater `p` will change.

I've read this [In Depth Guide to mod-rewrite](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708), but I'm still having issues.

I have made an attempt but I think it's brutally wrong:

```
// done by wordpress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mydomain/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /fundblack/index.php [L]

// added by me
RewriteCond ...need help here trying to ignore if there are query params... 
RewriteRule ^mydomain/?(\w+)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^mydomain/$ mydomain/dashboard
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

### Update

Albert's answer worked perfectly. Now I'm actually hosting the website on a server. The domain address is like this:

subdomain.subdomain.mydomain.com

is simply did this, but it's not working:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dashboard.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} !^/post_type=ignition_product&p=.*&preview=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dashboard/$1 [R=301,L]
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you give us the exact matching criteria for param1=2&param2=3 is param1 and param2 always the same, what about the value? If you say re-route do you mean redirect (URL will change in the browser) or rewrite (URL stay the same) but internally some other directory is processing the request?

Comment: @Webdesigner I added the params. One of them will change. I actually want to redirect to another address not rewrite the url.

Comment: But its alway on second position, right? And dashboard is a sub folder of mydomain in with the wordpress stuff is installed?

Comment: yes and yes it is

Comment: Will the query parameter change or the value of the query parameter? e.g post_type=other_product&t=23&preview=5  and if you have localhost:8080/mydomain/foo should this also go to localhost:8080/mydomain/dashboard/foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't two rewrite rules, just two conditions in the `.htaccess` inside `/mydomain/` folder:

```
RewriteBase /mydomain/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain/dashboard.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} !^/mydomain/post_type=ignition_product&p=.*&preview=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dashboard/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first condition prevents infinite loops if you try to access directly `localhost:8080/mydomain/dashboard/anything` and the second condition exclude URLs with that query string for any value of the `p` parameter (note that the missing `?` is not a typo because it's not included in the composed `%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING}`).

Also you don't need to use `/mydomain/` in the rule since you previously have `RewriteBase /mydomain/`.

---

*Edit:* For putting it in your final domain remove the `RewriteBase` since is not needed and put the `/` directly in the rule (I use it in the first answer because you have it defined in your  original `.htaccess`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dashboard.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} !^/post_type=ignition_product&p=.*&preview=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dashboard/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This  worked well but for some reason it removed the custom styles that I had on my website.

Comment: You mean custom styles for Wordpress? I'm not an expert but I suppose that they was saved with a full URL in the database, maybe you have to add exceptions also for the their files or folders (just add another condition similar to first one).

Comment: That was it!!!! Thank you. I just added conditions for sub-folders that resources(image/css/js) come from.

Comment: When I actually put this on a server and my domain looks like www.mydomain.com how then do I translate this?

Comment: Alberto, could you look at my update and offer some help you can

Comment: So in the real domain you want to redirect `subdomain.subdomain.mydomain.com/anything` to `subdomain.subdomain.mydomain.com/dashboard/anything`? Is that correct?

Comment: Alberto, Yes it is. That's exactly what I'd like to do

Comment: I've been busy, but I'll make some tests and will update the question if I find the problem.

Comment: I made some tests and the changes you made worked fine in my test environment, even with sudomains. I suspect that the `RewriteBase` may be interfering with other code in the `.htaccess`, test the updated rules.

Answer (score 0):

So in your WP Direcory `/mydomain/dashboard` you put just a gerneric WP .htaccess file if you like.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mydomain/dashboard/
    RewriteRule ^/?mydomain/dashboard/index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But in the `/mydomain` folder you put the folowing in your htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^post_type=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=([^&]+)&preview=([^&]+)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?mydomain/?$ 
    RewriteRule ^/?mydomain(/.*)?$ /mydomain/dashboard$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This version is as flexible es possible for your Query String, but if you like to have fixed values just change it to your needs.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` are in both cases optional but it will protect you from any server error if mod_rewrite is disabled.